# youtube-dl-exec issue - get readable stream

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js, youtube-dl

Im trying to get a readble stream from youtube-dl-exec.

```
youtubedl(url, {
    dumpSingleJson: true,
    noWarnings: true,
    audioFormat: 'mp3',
    //audioQuality: 0,
    noCheckCertificate: true,
    preferFreeFormats: true,
    youtubeSkipDashManifest: true,
    referer: 'https://google.com'
})
.then(async output => {
    let resource = createAudioResource(output); // output = YtResponse (JSON)
})
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

output is typeof YtResponse (JSON with formats and urls, thumbnails etc.)

So with

```
let url = output.formats[0]?.url;
```

I can get an URL like
`https://r1---sn-h0jelnez.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=`

But I can't stream this because it's not a readable stream..

So I tried to use `youtube-dl` library. But if I wan't to install it, i get this error:

```
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm run check && npm run download
npm ERR! > youtube-dl@3.5.0 check
npm ERR! > bin-version-check python '>=2'
npm ERR! Error: Invalid version range
npm ERR!     at module.exports (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Nodejs\LL-Bot-Musik\node_modules\bin-version-check\index.js:12:25)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Nodejs\LL-Bot-Musik\node_modules\bin-version-check-cli\cli.js:29:1)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Now I don't know what I can do..

Comment: It's something to do with invalid versions/compatibility

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it not send you JSON, all you have to do is remove `dumpSingleJson` or make it `false`.